# Call to Action with Authorize(Roles="Customer, Business") returns 500 error for those roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have several actions in my MVC site that recently started returning authentication errors when I call them when logged in with accounts that have the authorized roles. An example below.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer, Business")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowNotifications(bool unViewedOnly = true) {
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
    var notifications = await _notifications.GetByUserIdAsync(userId, unViewedOnly);
    return (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        ? PartialView("Notifications/NotificationsModal", notifications)
        : PartialView("Notifications/_Notifications", notifications);
}
```

I have not made any changes to the functions or the javascript that calls them in quite some time. I did recently update Microsofts Identity NuGet packages. Has anyone else seen this issue and does anyone have any idea how to fix it other than rolling back the Identity updates. I have no idea which library would have caused the problem. I am far from a security expert.

A typical response:

```
Key Value
X-Responded-JSON    {"status":401,"headers":{"location":"http:\/\/localhost:53033\/Account\/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FShared%2FShowNotifications%3FunViewedOnly%3DTrue%26modal%3DTrue%26X-Requested-With%3DXMLHttpRequest%26_%3D1426264188044"}}
```

Comment: I would look at the identity object that gets created on sign in. The roles should be a part of the claims token.

Comment: How do I observe this object? It's all hidden behind Ninject and the Identity Framework which I cannot seem to step into. Am I missing something?

Comment: Never mind. I figured out what you meant. I thought you were referring to something else.

Comment: Ok, upon observing the Identity object I see that it contains the roles required. The Action only works if I use [AllowAnonymous] [Authorize(Roles="xxxxx")] does not work. One thing that might be relevant is that I have an Authorize(Roles) for the class too. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes that could be the problem. You are allowed to stack Authorize attributes on top of each other. They don't "override".